# Android oreo - Foreground service once app is killed | android shows a notification

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-intentservice, android-8.1-oreo

App is targeting to 27 and I am testing on android **oreo 8.0 device**.

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
```

When user clicks on the **download** button, app starts a **foreground intent service** and also notifies the user through a notification.
Within the `onCreate` of `IntentService` , app also fulfils the promise to call the `startForeground(int id, Notification notification)` method.
So,

```
//On click of download button
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent);

//Within the onCreate() of IntentService()
startForeground(id, notification);
```

In case when app is in foreground, everything works perfect. But when user swiped out and thus kills the app; I restart the download and it works, downloading starts; but android system displays a notification - **"<#appname#> is running in background"**. 
So user now can see two notification

- one from my app showing the download progress and
- another from android system, showing that my app is running in background.

Is this fine? **How can I avoid the notification from android system?**

Here is how I manage swipe out app kill:

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {


    Context localContext = getApplicationContext();
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(localContext,
            HandlePendingDownload.class);
    restartServiceIntent.putExtra(DMConstants.ACTION_SWIPE_OUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            localContext, 1, restartServiceIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) localContext
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (FWCompat.isKitKat_19_OrNewer()) {
        alarmService.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1900,
                restartServicePendingIntent);
    } else {
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1900,
                restartServicePendingIntent);
    }
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

Then later within `onReceive()` I call :

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, downloadIntent);
```

**So to summarize,** 
Once the app is killed how to avoid the notification shown from android system, that the app is running in background? as I am already showing download notification to user, so the user is aware of that.

Also one more question, is there any way to get the intent withing `onCreate()` of `IntentService`? 
I need to get the id of download content, which is passed in the intent as extra param. Cause based on this I can show the notification within `onCreate()`

As of now I am showing one "starting download" notification, then in `onStartCommand()` I clear that notification and create a new notification based on content Id.

Answer (score 0):

From Android Documentation

> Foreground
>   A foreground service performs some operation that is noticeable to the user. For example, an audio app would use a foreground service to play an audio track. Foreground services must display a Notification. Foreground services continue running even when the user isn't interacting with the app.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

If the notification isn't properly started, then the service will be killed. Maybe you are looking for a different type of service. Maybe look into a bound service?

> Bound A service is bound when an application component binds to it by
>   calling bindService(). A bound service offers a client-server
>   interface that allows components to interact with the service, send
>   requests, receive results, and even do so across processes with
>   interprocess communication (IPC). A bound service runs only as long as
>   another application component is bound to it. Multiple components can
>   bind to the service at once, but when all of them unbind, the service
>   is destroyed.